# My list list_of_games is empty and i dont undestand why

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary, empty-list

Can someone tell me why my list list_of_games, I added the self.dicts to it. like you can see, when I print self.dict1 or self.dict2, they have something in it. I get no error this is why i could not post one.

```
 instances_dict = {0: {'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '}, 
                    1: {'halbzeit_h_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '}, 
                    2: {'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '}, 
                    3: {'halbzeit_h_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '}, 
                    4: {'halbzeit_h_tore': '2', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '}, 
                    5: {'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '}, 
                    6: {'halbzeit_h_tore': '3', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '}, 
                    7: {'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '}, 
                    8: {'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '}}
    
    
    class check_everygame_played_or_not :
        
        def __init__(self, dict1={}, dict2={}, dict3={}, dict4={}, dict5={}, dict6={}, dict7={}, dict8={}, 
                    dict9={}, dict10={}, dict11={}, dict12={}, list_of_games = [], played_games_of_the_day=[]):
            self.dict1 = dict1
            self.dict2 = dict2
            self.dict3 = dict3
            self.dict4 = dict4
            self.dict5 = dict5
            self.dict6 = dict6
            self.dict7 = dict7
            self.dict8 = dict8
            self.dict9 = dict9
            self.dict10 = dict10
            self.dict11 = dict11
            self.dict12 = dict12
            self.list_of_games = list_of_games
            self.played_games_of_the_day = played_games_of_the_day 
    
            #print(self.dict1)
    
            list_of_games = [
            self.dict1,
            self.dict2,
            self.dict3,
            self.dict4,
            self.dict5,
            self.dict6,
            self.dict7,
            self.dict8,
            self.dict9,
            self.dict10,
            self.dict11,
            self.dict12,
            ]
            print(self.list_of_games)
    
    
    test2 = check_everygame_played_or_not(*instances_dict.values())
```

Comment: You are passing 9 dicts to 14 variables and list_of_games is 13th, so no wonder why it's empty

Comment: I thought the  dicts that are to much are left as empty, But I can print them all from print(self.dict1) to print(self.dict9) and the rest like print(self.dict10) is empty like expected.

Comment: It works wenn i delet in init list_of_games = [] and self.played_games_of_the_day = played_games_of_the_day, mybe its overwritten somehow?